# skip part of a string and replace match with regular expression

Tags: javascript

I need to replace part of a string but the code I have replaces the whole string and I want to only relace the text after the = equals sign based on the key name. I need the regular expression to skip the key word value= and then replace the value that it equals. I have part of it working in the regular expression but it does a full match.

```
    /(?:value\=)([A-Za-z{}": ',&-=\\]+)$/

name = test
key = value
value = {
  "first": 'John',
  'Last': 'Doe'
}
value = first = John & last = Doe
```

[tester](https://regex101.com/r/9vMjD7/5)

```js
var data = "value=first_name=John&last_name=Doe;"
  .replace(/^(?:value\=)([A-Za-z{}": ',&-=\\]+)$/g, 'first_name=Homer&last_name=Simspon');

console.log(data);

/*     
 data = value=first_name=John&last_name=Doe
 which should be 
 value=first_name=Homer&last_name=Simspon
*/
```

Comment: The code you posted is invalid. Can you please tell once again what is the original string and what the expected result? It's not clear from what you provided.

Comment: What is the problem? If your regexp make a good job so take the first or the second match according to your "()".
Look at examples in doc for PHP function https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php

Comment: @Johny PHP function what? The tag is JavaScript.

Comment: I've updated it so it runs properly

Comment: How do I skip the key word value= in regular expresion and then match whats after it upto the character ";"

Comment: @ONYX well, like this: https://regex101.com/r/9vMjD7/6

Comment: Your task makes no sense to me, if you know upfront the things you want to replace, than why you just don't simply replace using `str.replace("foo", "bar")`. I think you have an XY Problem here.

Comment: Can you help me though, I know why I'm doing it this ways

Comment: Sure: `str.replace(/^value=.*$/gm, "value=bar")` that's all you need.

Comment: See [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/faw86Lm3/) and [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use capturing groups, $1, $2, etc. I've used the wildcard .* regex below, but you could probably make it more specific to the key-val pairs you expect to see.

```js
var data = "value=first_name=John&last_name=Doe;"
  .replace(/(value\=).*(;)/g, '$1first_name=Homer&last_name=Simspon$2');

console.log(data);

/*     
 data = value=first_name=John&last_name=Doe
 which should be 
 value=first_name=Homer&last_name=Simspon
*/
```

Comment: The reason I wanted to do this was to be able to set a cookie value in a cookie class that I built.